# jquery adding new elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i have this code

```
$.getJSON('check.php', function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {  
        $("#badge").append("<tr><td>"+val+"</td></tr><tr><td>-------------------------------------------------------</td></tr>");
    });
});

$("td").mouseover(function () {
    $(this).css("color","red");
});
```

my problem is when i hover my mouse cursor on each element they will not change color as what i expected... can someone explain me why??? and help me how to do the right thing.

Comment: Maybe try to remove `\``

Comment: At line 5 `});\`` you have an `\`` But look @manseUK 's answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The event `mouseover` will not fire as the element is not present on page on load ... so you need to do this :

```
$("#badge").on('mouseover','td', function () {
    $(this).css("color","red");
});
```

The [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) functions will be triggered on the `badge` element (which is a table im guessing) and will only trigger when the event target is a `td` and the event is `mouseover`.

One thing to note though - this could easily be done with css :

```
#badge td:hover {
   color: red;
}
```

Thanks @WTK :

Keep in mind, that `on()` is available starting jQuery 1.7. For older versions of jQuery and similar outcome use either `bind()`, `delegate()` or `live()`.

Comment: Keep in mind, that `on()` is available starting jQuery 1.7. For older versions of jQuery and similar outcome use either `bind()`, `delegate()` or `live()`. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @JulianPaoloDayag *it doesn't work* .. errors ? anything ? is the event triggered ?

Comment: @ManseUK - your point being? I'm simply pointing out that `on()` may not be available in OP version of jQuery.

Comment: @WTK - sorry you are right - I will add a warning to the answer (and dumb comment removed!)

Comment: i know sir that it can be done on css.... but it is not only for hovering effect i planned... and if i can understand how to fix this.... i can also do my other stuffs related to this

Answer (score 1):

Try using `live` or `on` because your elements are loaded dynamically. Basically what these functions do is allow you to attach event handlers to future elements. Use it like so:

```
$("td").on('mouseover', function(){
    $(this).css({'color':'#F00'})
});
```